# What is Hyperledger-bevel? Can it be used with Hyperledger-fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

With regard to Hyperledger software, I'm a novice. I see a lot of similarities between Hyperledger-fabric and Hyperledger-bevel.
What Hyperledger-fabric-compatible technologies can I use to create a consortium blockchain if I wish to?

Answer (score 0):

Hyperledger Bevel is a framework for deploying and managing various distributed ledger technologies (DLTs). Hyperledger Fabric is one of the DLTs that you can deploy with Hyperledger Bevel. More information can be found in the [Bevel readme](https://github.com/hyperledger/bevel#readme).